# Getting all possible ranges by matching using regular expressions in Swift

Tags: regex, swift

I'm playing with the following code in Swift to build an appropriate regex for an application:

```
let regExp = "-(\\([0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+\\)|[0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+)"

let testString = "-(hsjshdf)   -hsghsgsgs -(k) -(1/64) -dhsg62 -(p)"

let regularExpression = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: regExp, options: [])

let matchesArray = regularExpression.matches(in: testString, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: testString.characters.count))

for match in matchesArray {
    for i in 0..<match.numberOfRanges {
        let range = match.rangeAt(i)
        let r = testString.index(testString.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location) ..< testString.index(testString.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location + range.length)
        print(testString.substring(with: r))
    }
}
```

The result I get is as follows:

```
-(hsjshdf)
(hsjshdf)
-hsghsgsgs
hsghsgsgs
-(k)
(k)
-(1/64)
(1/64)
-dhsg62
dhsg62
-(p)
(p)
```

However, I want the regexp match and group the substring within "()", so I can get the following output:

```
-(hsjshdf)
(hsjshdf)
hsjshdf
-hsghsgsgs
hsghsgsgs
-(k)
(k)
k
-(1/64)
(1/64)
1/64
-dhsg62
dhsg62
-(p)
(p)
p
```

I tried the following modification to the original regex, and it worked for the substring "-(hsjshdf)" but crashed when printing the matches of the substring "-hsghsgsgs" with an execution time error (fatal error: cannot increment beyond endIndex):

```
let regExp = "-(\\(([0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+)\\)|[0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+)"
```

I'm not familiar with NSRegularExpression. Am I using the wrong regexp? Do I need to set an special option?

Thanks for your help. Kindest regards.

/TB

Comment: Please show your code which generates _The result_ _as follows_. The code you have shown does not generate such result.

Comment: Done. Sorry for the inconvenience, I forgot to include the loops that traverse through the ranges and subranges since I assumed the problem is not in those loops.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the problem resides in the loops.

You know that you have two pairs of capturing parentheses in your regex `let regExp = "-(\\(([0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+)\\)|[0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+)"`, and the latter (the inner) one may not capture any parts of the string.

One thing you should know is that `NSRegularExpression` returns `NSRange(location: NSNotFound, length: 0)` for missing captures. In the current implementation, `NSNotFound` has the same value as `Int.max` which may be far greater than any actual Strings.

You just need to check if `location` of the ranges is `NSNotFound` or not, before using them:

```
let regExp = "-(\\(([0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+)\\)|[0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+)"

let testString = "-(hsjshdf)   -hsghsgsgs -(k) -(1/64) -dhsg62 -(p)"

let regularExpression = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: regExp, options: [])

//###(1) Use `.utf16.count`, not `.characters.count`.
let matchesArray = regularExpression.matches(in: testString, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: testString.utf16.count))

for match in matchesArray {
    for i in 0..<match.numberOfRanges {
        let range = match.rangeAt(i)
        if range.location == NSNotFound {continue} //###(2) Skip missing captures.
        //###(3) Your way of creating `r` does not work for non-BMP characters.
        print((testString as NSString).substring(with: range))
    }
}
```

(My comments (1) and (3) are not critical for your input `testString`, but you should also know that `NSRegularExpression` works with `NSString`s which are represented in UTF-16 based format internally. The `location` and `length` represent the UTF-16 based offset and count, not `Characters` based.)

Comment: Thank you very much OOPer, your corrections and comments were illustrative. I still don't get why matching substrings like "-hsghsgsgs" with the option [0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+ of the regexp results in the NSNotFound situation, given that such option doesn't contain inner capturing parenthesis as the other option does. Could you please explain or provide a link to a text?

Comment: You'd better check how your pattern `"-(\\(([0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+)\\)|[0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+)"` matches the substring like `"-hsghsgsgs"`. You have two subpatterns after `-` inside the outer capture, `\\(([0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+)\\)` and `[0-9.a-z()+-×÷√^₁₀²³/]+`. The string `hsghsgsgs` does not enclosed in parentheses, so the latter matches, the first does not match. The range corresponding to the capture which is included in the non-matching subpattern returns `NSNotFound`.